# VB] How to initialize 2nd array in struct

Tags: vb.net, 2d

An error occurs in the place to initialize the array.

How Can I Use that array ?

It must be a two-dimensional array of character...

Thank you....

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, Pack:=1)> _
Public Structure ST_TEST
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=360)>
    Public 2D_CHAR_ARR()() As Char  '//Array In Struct can not be fixed row&col
End Structure

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim stTest As ST_TEST
ReDim stTest.2D_CHAR_ARR(60)(60)   ' //throws System.NullReferenceException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null reference is occurring because your array as you have defined it isn't a square array but an array of arrays. To `ReDim` it you need to write something like

```
ReDim MyArray(60)

For i As Integer = 0 To 60
    ReDim MyArray(i)(60)
Next i
```

If a square array is what you wanted, you should declare it

```
Public MyArray(60, 60)
```

Comment: Despite the basic question, thank you for writing the answers.
I am honored to be able to learn new knowledge.
Thank you very much!
Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-dimensional array

```
Dim matrix = New Integer(4, 4) {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}
```

Jagged array

```
Dim sales()() As Double = New Double(11)() {}
```

From [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)